# Different behavior of Spark Dataset for java.util.UUID

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark 2.0.0 and creating a `Dataset` using `SparkSession`. When I use `java.util.UUID` in `createDataFrame` method it works fine. But when I have `java.util.UUID` as a field in Javabean and when I use this Javabean to create Dataset, it gives me `scala.MatchError`. Please see the code and console log below. Can any one tell me what is going on here and how can I create `Dataset` with `UUID` in Javabean class. Thanks.

**UUIDTest.java**

```
public class UUIDTest { 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     SparkSession spark = SparkSession
              .builder()
              .appName("UUIDTest")
              .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/file:C:/temp")
              .master("local[2]")
              .getOrCreate();

     System.out.println("====> Create Dataset using UUID"); 

     //Working
     List<UUID> uuids = Arrays.asList(UUID.randomUUID(),UUID.randomUUID());      
     Dataset<Row> uuidSet = spark.createDataFrame(uuids, UUID.class);        
     uuidSet.show();

     System.out.println("====> Create Dataset using UserUUID"); 

     //Not Working
     List<UserUUID> userUuids = Arrays.asList(new UserUUID(UUID.randomUUID()),new UserUUID(UUID.randomUUID()));
     Dataset<Row> userUuidSet = spark.createDataFrame(userUuids, UserUUID.class);//Exception at this line        
     userUuidSet.show();    

     spark.stop();
   }
}
```

**UserUUID.java**

```
public class UserUUID implements Serializable{

private UUID uuid;

public UserUUID() {
}

public UserUUID(UUID uuid) {
    this.uuid = uuid;
}

public UUID getUuid() {
    return uuid;
}

public void setUuid(UUID uuid) {
    this.uuid = uuid;
  }
}
```

**Console output**

```
16/08/26 22:49:23 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is '/file:C:/temp'.
====> Create Dataset using UUID
16/08/26 22:49:26 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 248.230818 ms
16/08/26 22:49:26 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 10.550477 ms
+--------------------+-------------------+
|leastSignificantBits|mostSignificantBits|
+--------------------+-------------------+
|-6786538026241948655|5045373365275148508|
|-9161219066266259673|6040751881536491488|
+--------------------+-------------------+

====> Create Dataset using UserUUID
Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: 4fa3941c-f312-4031-a61b-01f2acef751b (of class java.util.UUID)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:256)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:251)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:103)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:403)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$beansToRows$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:1106)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$beansToRows$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:1106)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$beansToRows$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:1106)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$beansToRows$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:1104)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.toStream(Iterator.scala:1322)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toStream(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toSeq(TraversableOnce.scala:298)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toSeq(Iterator.scala:1336)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:373)
at com.UUIDTest.main(UUIDTest.java:30)
16/08/26 22:49:26 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

Comment: I am having the exact same issue.  Did you ever find a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with so many attempts to get it working while facing this problem, the only solution I found is to use `list<text>` rather than `list<uuid>` and make the mapping in java level when I want to use the UUID using the method: `UUID.fromString(uuidStr)`